# Virtual machine test suite

Tags: windows, macos, vmware, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I just got some VM software installed on my MacBook in order to have a test suite for cross-compatibility on websites etc. I need to be able to test for Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

Am I right in assuming I should install both Windows XP (with IE7) and Windows 7 (with IE8) to get the most optimal setup?

Answer (score 2):

the result of testing the website with ie7 and ie8 doesn't depend on the windows version only on the browser version. 
You can also run the ie8 in the compatibility mode but I made the experience that the result of ie7 and ie8 compatibility mode is not 100% the same.

Comment: Yes, I know. But as it's not possible to run several versions of IE on the same operating system - I need two installments of Windows, no?